# iOS read xml data from a server with authentication

Tags: ios, xml, xml-parsing

In my app I've to read xml data from a server. To access to this server it's necessary to give an username and a password, how I can solve that?
I tried to read xml data with this code:

```
-(id)sendRequestToURL:(NSString*)url withMethod:(NSString*)method {
    NSURL *finalUrl;
    if ([method isEqualToString:@"GET"]) {
        finalUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Metodo non implementato");
    }
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:finalUrl];
    [request setHTTPMethod:method];
    [request setValue:@"x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (connection) {
        [connection start];
    }
    return connection;
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Ho ricevuto una risposta");
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"Ho ricevuto dei dati: %@", data);
    NSMutableData *test = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    [test appendData:data];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Ho terminato di caricare");
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

It connect correctly but if I try to read what's the problem I'm getting this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>401 Authorization Required</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Authorization Required</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at 54.204.6.246 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

So I guess that it's necessary to give username and password but how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

base64EncodedString Set the authentication header field:

```
NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", @"myusername", @"mypassword"];
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedString]];
[request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

To convert NSData to base64 String you need [NSData+Base64.h](https://gist.github.com/Abizern/1643491)

Comment: Ok, how I can integrate the `NSData+Base64.h`? It's enough to download the code in link you posted here and insert directly in my code?

Comment: Yes, just place the header file and the implementation on your Project, then added import to NSData+Base64.h.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue in this way:

```
    NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://54.204.6.246/magento8/api/rest/products/?category_id=3"];
    [self sendRequestToURL:address withMethod:@"GET"];

    -(id)sendRequestToURL:(NSString*)url withMethod:(NSString*)method {
    NSURL *finalUrl;
    if ([method isEqualToString:@"GET"]) {
        finalUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Metodo non previsto");
    }
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:finalUrl];
    [request setHTTPMethod:method];
    NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", @"user", @"password"];
    NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedString]];
    [request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request setValue:@"x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (connection) {
        [connection start];
    }
    return connection;
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Ho ricevuto una risposta");
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"Ho ricevuto dei dati: %@", data);
    jsonCategory = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Ho terminato di caricare");
    JsonCategoryReader *reader = [[JsonCategoryReader alloc]init];
    [reader parseJson:jsonCategory];

}
```

I hope it's useful for other people who has the same problem. (watch out the code it's just a snipped and probably there aren't all the {})